# Create a function funcA that receives an array of numbers and return their sum after 2 seconds

Tags: javascript

**HTML**

```js
var array1 = [5, 5, 6];

var promi = new Promise(function A(mResolve, mReject) {
  var total = array1.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  setTimeout(function A() {
    mResolve(' array of 5+5+6= ' + total);
  }, 2000);
});

promi.then(function A(value) {
  document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = value;
});

var num = 3;
var prom = new Promise(function B(Resolve, Reject) {
  var funcb = array1.reduce(function (funcb, total) {
    return total * num;
  });
  setTimeout(function B() {
    Resolve(' mul of 16*3  =' + funcb);
  }, 1000);
});

prom.then(function B(value) {
  document.getElementById('mul').innerHTML = value;
});
```

**Full question**

> Create a function `funcA` that receives an array of numbers and return
> their sum after 2 seconds.
> Create a function `funcB` that receives a number, call `funcA` after 1
> second and returns the `mul` of the number with `funcA` result

Why in the html page at total saved as the last index in array, this case its saved as 6 not as 16?

The last answer should be `16 * 3 = 48`

Comment: `funcb` is never called? --- `total` is not accessible outside of `A` --- `prom` doesn't wait for `promi` to be finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your goal is something like this:
Wait for the `function A` to add values so that you can use that sum for multiplication in the `function B`.

To make things easier, here I'm going to use `promiseA`(instead of `function A`) and `promiseB`(instead of `function B`). You can get the `sum` value without using `setTimeout` by declaring a global `var total;`. Just have a look at the snippet below:

**Example without using `setTimeout:`**

```js
var array1 = [5, 5, 6], total;

var promiseA = new Promise((mResolve, mReject) => {
    total = array1.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    mResolve("array of 5+5+6 = " + total);
})

promiseA.then((value) => {
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = value;
});

var num = 3;
var promiseB = new Promise((Resolve, Reject) => {
    Resolve("mul of 16*3  = " + total * num);
})

promiseB.then((value) => {
    document.getElementById("mul").innerHTML = value;
});
```

```html
<h2 id="sum"></h2>
<h2 id="mul"></h2>
```

**Example using `setTimeout:`**

```js
var array1 = [5, 5, 6], total;

var promiseA = new Promise((mResolve, mReject) => {
    total = array1.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    setTimeout(() => {
        mResolve("After 2 seconds, array of 5+5+6 = " + total);
    }, 2000);
})

promiseA.then((value) => {
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = value;
});

var num = 3;
var promiseB = new Promise((Resolve, Reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        Resolve("After 1 second, mul of 16*3  = " + total * num);
    }, 1000);
})

promiseB.then((value) => {
    document.getElementById("mul").innerHTML = value;
});
```

```html
<h2 id="sum"></h2>
<h2 id="mul"></h2>
```